# How to @Inject values from a .properties file with CDI

Tags: properties, dependency-injection, cdi

How can i inject some values from a properties file?
I have a .properties file with some keys and values, i would like to inject those to use on some classes, something like:

```
@Inject(file = "/WEB-INF/abc.properties",key ="path")
private String path;
```

So when i use the path it has the value from the properties file, instead of going thorough the entire process of reading the properties and getting the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there has been active discussion about [integrating configuration in CDI](http://javaeeconfig.blogspot.fr/2014/09/integrating-configuration-with-cdi-20.html), the current status is that there won't be a standard [Java configuration JSR](http://javaeeconfig.blogspot.fr/2014/09/no-java-ee-configuration-for-ee8-dear.html) anytime soon.

In the meantime, configuration integration is provided by third-parties like [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/), see http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html so that it is possible to write:

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "endpoint.poll.interval")
private Integer pollInterval;
```

That relies on the service loader meachanism to extend the configuration sourcing.

The [Apache Tamaya](http://tamaya.incubator.apache.org/index.html) project plans to have [CDI integration](http://tamaya.incubator.apache.org/modules.html#cdi-integration) as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example of use? Where the .properties would go and how to call then correctly?

Comment: I assume the apache deltaspike documentation has examples…  did you check?